# Check for null inside null-coalescing operator

Tags: c#, resharper

I am using Resharper and usually that thingy underlines me parts of code which might throw null reference exception. But in this case Resharper seems to think the code is fine. Why?

```
public static bool Check<T>(IEnumerable<T> docs)
{
   var list = docs as IList<T> ?? docs.ToList();
   return list.Count == 3;
}
```

Resharper is not underlining me anything here. What am I missing here? There should be an exception if docs is null. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Crashes with what exception? I guess `ArgumentNullException` ?

Comment: In case docs is not implementing IList<..> or docs is null from begin on the docs.ToList() will be executed and there the code should crash but to resharper the code seems fine. Why?

Comment: This looks like a bug in ReSharper. Consider filing a bug report.

Comment: we are not resharper support team.

Comment: @devhedgehog This code will crash only when `docs` is null, not when `docs` doesn't implement `IList<T>`. This is the expected behavior and not a bug. Resharper won't check for null parameters. You have to do yourself. It won't even give you a hint.

Comment: Have you tried annotating the parameter with `[NotNull]`, assuming you've got the annotations referenced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ReSharper checks for **NullReferenceExceptions** but IEnumerable.ToList() throws an **ArgumentNullException**.

It makes sense. You may pass in an object that implements the null pattern which ReSharper probably wouldn't know about, this could result in wrong and annoying warnings so I assume that this would be difficult to implement in ReSharper